# how to a run a windows desktop application from a console application

Tags: c++

i currently have a game engine that i have developed during my university course.

i need to run the engine  with the following function

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    // engine runs in here
}
```

from a console application:

```
int main()
{

}
```

is there a way to rename the wWinMain function to something like StartEngine()
and run that from main function in the console application?

forgive me if this is a stupid question, I have looked everywhere and even asked some of my tutors and still cant find an answer.

Comment: What's the problem with just running your app as a windowed app? Why do you need to start it as a console app?

Comment: You can certainly rename a function and call it from another function.  What's the difficulty you had when you tried that?  Also, is there any real reason to combine the game engine and the console application into one program?  You might want to just execute the game engine from your console application, the same way you would run any external program, depending on what level of coordination you need between the two pieces of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

circling back round and posting what ended up being the answer:

I ended up only needing 1 of the 4 parameters so I was able to rename the function and I was able to get the first parameter using GetModuleHandle(0)

these are the snippets from the same two files:

[console application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjNxf.png)

[windows application now being run from the console application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od1FM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to start a windows application from another, perhaps a console one.

```
void Starter( const std::wstring exec_filename )
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof(si) );
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof(pi) );

    wchar_t cmd[100];
    snwprintf(cmd,99,exec_filename.c_str());

    si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE
    si.wShowWindow = wShowWindow;
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USEPOSITION;
    si.dwX = 600;
    si.dwY = 200;


    if( !CreateProcess( NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
                        cmd,            // Command line
                        NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
                        NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
                        FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
                        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE,              //  creation flags
                        NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
                        NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory
                        &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                        &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
      )
    {
        int syserrno = GetLastError();
        if( syserrno == 2 )
        {
            NotifyUserOfError( wxString::Format("Cannot find executable file %S in working directory\n",
                                                exec_filename) );
            return;
        }
        SetStatusText( wxString::Format("Sysem error no (%d)\n", GetLastError()) );
        wchar_t * lpMsgBuf;
        FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            (DWORD) syserrno,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPWSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
            0, NULL );

        char errorbuf[200];
        snprintf(errorbuf,199,
                 "Error is %S",
                 lpMsgBuf);
        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);

        return;
    }

    // Close process and thread handles.
    CloseHandle( pi.hProcess );
    CloseHandle( pi.hThread );
}
```